# How to use a large meshgrid without memory error in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to reproduce the following plot:

[image]

I am working with a function of two variables: `skin_depth(T,rho)`.
So I decided to use the `meshgrid` and to plot using `contourlines`.
The problem is it only works for a small range of `T` and `rho`.
When I try to use the range for x and y axis like in the figure above,
the following error message appears:

---

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 T = np.linspace(0.01,10000,10000)
>         2 rho = np.linspace(0.1,100000,1000000)
>   ----> 3 X, Y = np.meshgrid(T,rho)
>
> C:\Users\paula\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc
>   in meshgrid(*xi, **kwargs)    4696     4697     if copy_:
>   -> 4698         output = [x.copy() for x in output]    4699     4700     return output
>
> MemoryError:

Does anyone know a way to avoid it?
Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0.01,100,10000)
rho = np.linspace(0.1,1000,10000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(T,rho)

skin_depth = 500*(np.sqrt(Y*X))

levels=np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
CS = plt.contour(X,Y,skin_depth, levels, colors='k')
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=9, inline=1, inlinespacing=1, fmt='%1.f')
plt.grid(True,which="both",ls="-")
plt.title('Skin Depth (m)')
plt.xlabel('Period [T(s)] ')
plt.ylabel('Resistivity [rho(ohm.m)]')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: i can run this fine, i suggest just reducing your grid if possible? check when youre running how your system ram usage is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are creating more than necessary intermediate mesh points with your `linspace` for your plot.

You were doing:

```
T = np.linspace(0.01,10000,10000)
rho = np.linspace(0.1,1000000,1000000)
print (len(T)*len(rho))
> 10000000000
```

which means you were creating a meshgrid of **10 billion** data points.

In reality, you need a `logspace`. The mesh points you need are `0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ... 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ...1, 2, 3,... 10, 20, 30, ... 100, 200, 300,...1000, 2000, 3000,...` and so on since you are on a logarithmic coordinate system. You can print `T` and `rho` now to see what I mean. By doing so, you only need **3402 data points**.

So you were basically creating **seven orders of magnitude** more data points than necessary.

Here is a modified initial data with the output. You can add more levels to show up as solid black lines

```
a1 = np.logspace(-2, 4, 7)  # Alternative a1 = 10.**(np.arange(-2, 5))
a2 = np.arange(1,10,1)
a3 = np.logspace(-1, 4, 6)  # Alternative a3 = 10.**(np.arange(-1, 5))

T = np.outer(a1, a2).flatten()
rho = np.outer(a3, a2).flatten()

X, Y = np.meshgrid(T,rho)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5.5))
# Your code here
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! I had tried to use the logspace before, but I didn't know about the second step with the outer product and flatten. It's working very well now.